# How to dynamically map over object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to dynamically insert a list of values as the key to be mapped over. The list here is `employeeTypes`. I need to `map()` over every `role.supervisors` and every `role.employees`..

Attempt:

```
export default function EmployeesByDepartmentList({ department }) {
  const employeeTypes = ["supervisors", "employees"];

  return (
    <div className={styles.departmentSection} key={department.id}>
      {department.roles.length
        ? department.roles.map((role) =>

            employeeTypes.forEach((type) => { // this is my attempt at iterating over each item in employeeTypes to use as the role key

                role[type].map((item) => (

                  <ListLinkItem
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    href={`employees/${item.id}/`}
                  >
                    <EmployeeImage
                      src={item.image}
                      alt={item.first_name + item.last_name}
                    />
                  </ListLinkItem>
                ));
              })
        )
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am sure it is easy, I just can't seem to visualize what I need atm. All help appreciated!

Edit:

This is the department object:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "employees": [],
            "supervisors": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "role": "Casino Supervisor",
                    "last_login": "2022-05-06T13:34:44.934187-07:00",
                    "is_superuser": false,
                    "username": "T2Admin1",
                    "is_staff": true,
                    "is_active": true,
                    "date_joined": "2022-04-06T19:42:22-07:00",
                    "first_name": "T2Admin",
                    "last_name": "Admin1",
                    "badge_num": "1234",
                    "email_notifications": true,
                    "sms_notifications": true,
                    "points": 0,
                    "image": "/media/images/profile_pics/dealer.jpg",
                    "supervisor": null,
                    "company": 2,
                    "groups": [
                        1,
                        3
                    ],
                    "user_permissions": []
                },
            ],
            "name": "Casino Supervisor",
            "supervisor": null,
            "group": 1,
            "company": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "role": "Dealer",
                    "last_login": null,
                    "is_superuser": false,
                    "username": "T2Dealer2",
                    "is_staff": false,
                    "is_active": true,
                    "date_joined": "2022-04-06T19:32:08-07:00",
                    "first_name": "T2Dealer",
                    "last_name": "Dealer2",
                    "badge_num": "1234",
                    "email_notifications": true,
                    "sms_notifications": true,
                    "points": 0,
                    "image": "/media/images/profile_pics/dealer.jpg",
                    "supervisor": null,
                    "company": 2,
                    "groups": [
                        2
                    ],
                    "user_permissions": []
                },
            ],
            "supervisors": [],
            "name": "Dealer",
            "supervisor": null,
            "group": 2,
            "company": 2
        }
    ],
    "created_on": "2022-04-14T16:15:27.299700-07:00",
    "updated_on": "2022-04-21T12:31:24.773872-07:00",
    "name": "Casino"
}
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. It just iterates. It would help to have a [mcve] rather than "do something with item" which, in the context of the code you've provided, is fairly meaningless, and doesn't help us debug the problem. What does your input data look like (a sample), and what output are you expecting?

Comment: You will have to show roles object along with what you are trying to do

Comment: @Andy thank you for the input. I have updated to show the department object as well as a minimal reproducible example. Apologies for not providing enough info the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
const department = {
  "id": 2,
  "roles": [{
      "id": 1,
      "employees": [],
      "supervisors": [{
        "id": 8,
        "role": "Casino Supervisor",
        "last_login": "2022-05-06T13:34:44.934187-07:00",
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "T2Admin1",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2022-04-06T19:42:22-07:00",
        "first_name": "T2Admin",
        "last_name": "Admin1",
        "badge_num": "1234",
        "email_notifications": true,
        "sms_notifications": true,
        "points": 0,
        "image": "/media/images/profile_pics/dealer.jpg",
        "supervisor": null,
        "company": 2,
        "groups": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "user_permissions": []
      }, ],
      "name": "Casino Supervisor",
      "supervisor": null,
      "group": 1,
      "company": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "employees": [{
        "id": 4,
        "role": "Dealer",
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "T2Dealer2",
        "is_staff": false,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2022-04-06T19:32:08-07:00",
        "first_name": "T2Dealer",
        "last_name": "Dealer2",
        "badge_num": "1234",
        "email_notifications": true,
        "sms_notifications": true,
        "points": 0,
        "image": "/media/images/profile_pics/dealer.jpg",
        "supervisor": null,
        "company": 2,
        "groups": [
          2
        ],
        "user_permissions": []
      }, ],
      "supervisors": [],
      "name": "Dealer",
      "supervisor": null,
      "group": 2,
      "company": 2
    }
  ],
  "created_on": "2022-04-14T16:15:27.299700-07:00",
  "updated_on": "2022-04-21T12:31:24.773872-07:00",
  "name": "Casino"
}

department.roles.map(role => {
  role.employees.map(employee => console.log("do something with this employee: ", employee))
  role.supervisors.map(supervisor => console.log("do something with this supervisor: ", supervisor))
})
```

Comment: So, this is what I had previously but the return value of both `employee => ` and `supervisor =>` are the same, so I am trying to go back optimize a bit (since the prototype is done).

Comment: You could possibly make a single function which gets called in both the `do something with this employee` and the `do something with this supervisor` sections?

Comment: That's true, and actually a great way to go about it! I didn't think about it that way. Check my answer for the way I did it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be roughly what you're looking for. Your first goal is to get all relevant people into one flat array. After that, it's easy to iterate using `Array#map`. Something along the lines of this:

```js
export default function EmployeesByDepartmentList({ department }) {
  const employeeTypes = ['supervisors', 'employees'];
  const allPeople = employeeTypes
    .map(type => department.roles.find(role => type in role)?.[type])
    .filter(Boolean)
    .flat();

  return (
    <div className={styles.departmentSection} key={department.id}>
      {allPeople.map(person => (
        <ListLinkItem key={person.id} id={person.id} href={`employees/${person.id}/`}>
          <EmployeeImage src={person.image} alt={person.first_name + person.last_name} />
          <div className={styles.employeeCardInfoContainer}>
            <div className={styles.listItemTitle}>
              {person.first_name} {person.last_name}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.employeeCardRole}>{person.role}</div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.employeeCardButtonContainer}>
            <ArrowCircleIcon />
          </div>
        </ListLinkItem>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your component like this. Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/embed/goofy-aryabhata-4bbonf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {department.roles.map((role) =>
              (role?.supervisors?.map((supervisor) => (
                    <div>{supervisor?.id}</div>
              ))).concat((role?.employees?.map((employee) => (
                    <div>{employee?.id}</div>
              ))))
      )
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of GitHub CoPilot (writing psuedocode comments), I was able to solve the problem using `employeeTypes.map()` then making sure that the `Array.Prototype()` has a `return` statement in it - as such:

```
export default function EmployeesByDepartmentList({ department }) {
  const employeeTypes = ["supervisors", "employees"];

  return (
    <div className={styles.departmentSection} key={department.id}>
      {department.roles.length
        ? department.roles.map((role) =>
            // iterate over each role, with each employeeType as the key
            employeeTypes.map((employeeType) => {
              // return the employees
              return role[employeeType].map((item) => (
                <ListLinkItem
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}
                  href={`employees/${item.id}/`}
                >
                    <EmployeeImage
                      src={item.image}
                      alt={item.first_name + item.last_name}
                    />
                  </ListLinkItem>
                ));
              })
        )
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```